# Jenkins agents on GKE/GCE

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-compute-engine, cloud-computing

I am using Jenkins to build my Angular applications on Google
Kubernetes Engine (GKE).  At some point I noticed that the builds on GKE take
significantly longer than it used to take on my old (private) environment so I
started to perform some tests.  It takes twice the amount of time in all cases on GCE.  AWS, on the other hand is within a few % of my old private environment so I used it for comparison.

I slowly removed all the layers (Jenkins, Kubernetes, etc...) and kept
getting the same result.  When running the builds directly on
`n1-standard-1` and `n1-highcpu-4` instances on GCE and on a `t2-medium` instance on AWS for comparison, this is what I get:

```
     Instance     | vCPUs | Mem  | Duration | Cost/Build
------------------+-------+------+----------+-----------
GCE:n1-standard-1 |     1 | 3.7G | 610642ms |    $0.0089
GCE:n1-highcpu-4  |     4 | 3.6G | 472999ms |    $0.018
AWS:t2-medium     |     2 | 4.0G | 373039ms |    $0.0051
```

I understand that one vCPU in GCE is backed by one hyper-thread but
looking at the table above, it is obvious that in GCE, the build takes longer and I am paying more.  Even though using a `n1-highcpu-4` I pay much more for the vCPU than a `t2-medium`, it still takes longer to run the same workload.

Am I missing any machine type from Google that is more optimized for
this kind of CPU intensive workload?  Is anyone else running builds on GCE/GKE?